# Convert an array of ['[object HTMLCanvasElement]'] into a string to get the element "id" so I can select a specific element on the web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic html page that has three canvas elements all with unique id's. I have collected the elements into an array using javascript's document.querySelectAll('canvas'). If I do a function using for each on the array, I can see all the info **BUT** if I try to extract that info so I can split it and get the id value, it doesn't work. I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. Am I trying to do something that cannot be done?

**!IMPORTANT!**: This has to be done in vanilla javascript, not third party libraries are allowed of any kind. Its due to security reasons, and that's all I can say on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title> Canvas Graph </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the id here will be used to set the height of the canvas to be created -->
        <div> 
            <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    document.onload = getCanvasId();
    
    function getCanvasId() {
    const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
    const elementArray = [...elementList];
    var temp = [];
    var stringArray = [];
    
    elementArray.forEach(element => {      
        temp.push(element);
        console.log(element);
    });
    
    for(i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
        stringArray[i] = temp[i].toString();
        console.log(stringArray);
    }

    temp.forEach(element => {
        var t = element.toString().split("#");
        console.log(t);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend printing the html to console with `console.dir()` to check the HTML DOM properties available for a particular element.

And you would access an id of an element using its `id` property - [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).

```js
const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
var stringArray = [];

elementList.forEach(element => {
  stringArray.push(element.id);
});

console.log(stringArray);
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
</div>
```